# Populate Select From Query On Page Load

Tags: php, html, arrays, joomla

I want to execute a query, and populate a Select with the returned result set on the page load.  So when the page has fully loaded the Select will have options.  I have this syntax, but there is about a 10 - 15 second delay from page load to Select list population.  Is there a syntax issue, or a better way to set this up so the population is timed perfectly/

```
    <html>
<?php
    //Connect to the database
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bible");

    //Return an error if we have a connection issue
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
                . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }

    $query = $mysqli->query("select empID as Name from employees");

    while($array[] = $query->fetch_object());

    array_pop($array);
?>
    <h3>Employee List:</h3>
    <select name="the_name">
    <?php foreach($array as $option) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option->Name; ?>"></option>
    </select>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
Here is full syntax (from my actual page) and now I am getting a 500 Error whenever I try to load the page?

```
<form method="POST">
<html>
<tbody>  
Hire Date:<input type="date" name="hiredate" value="<?=$_POST['hiredate']?>">
Term Date:<input type="date" name="termdate" value="<?=$_POST['termdate']?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<select name="InvoiceNum">
<?php 
$option = array();
$option['driver'] = 'mssql'; 
$option['host'] = 'IP ADDRESS'; 
$option['user'] = 'user name'; 
$option['password'] = 'password'; 
$option['database'] = 'database'; 
$option['prefix'] = '';
$db = JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
$sql = $db->getQuery(true);
$sql = mssqli_query($connection, "SELECT InvoiceNum FROM MonthlyInvoices ORDER BY InvoiceNum ASC");
$db->setQuery($sql); 
$sql = $db->loadObjectList();
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option value=\"{$row['InvoiceNum']}\">{$row['InvoiceNum']}</option>";
}
?>
</select></tbody></html> </form>
```

Comment: You are hiting the db and then running a while loop to save all the entries in an array instead the results return by db query should be already in array format... check it, I think this would remove the while loop and could optimise your page load time.

Comment: Get your data into a variable before looping through it to build the html. How many records roughly are loading 10-15 seconds is a long time are you loading thousands of rows to that list?

Comment: @Danny - always less than < 500.  Typically only 150ish

Comment: Use either joomla API or pure mysqli. Can't get that mix.

Comment: @Deadooshka - How am I mixing the two?